# google music creative solution

Tags: google-music

I have around 1000 songs synced with Google Music. Recently, I had to delete my local folder with music (the hard drive was defective). Now, when it came down to downloading all my music from Google to my new drive, it got stuck towards the end for some reason and I had to cancel the task because it wasn't progressing. So the end result is that there are some 10 songs in the cloud that don't exist locally.

The problem is that when I try to restart downloading my songs from the google music client, it starts redownloading all my songs! I really don't want to do that, as it will mess up the organization and will drain lots of bandwidth.

Does anyone have an idea for how to figure out which 10 or so songs I don't have locally, without downloading everything again? For some reason it's bothering me a lot that I don't have all the songs and don't even know which ones are missing haha.

Is there some way to export a plain text list of songs from the browser client of google play, or something along those lines, instead of navigating the GUI through thousand songs and verifying each one exists locally?

Thanks